# Do I have to use -fPIC to create a shared object library?

Tags: linux, fortran, shared-libraries, gfortran

I am using the default gfortran on Ubuntu 18.04.

I used the following commands to create a shared object library.

```
gfortran -Wall -g -c myMultiply.f90
gfortran -Wall -g -c mySum.f90
gfortran -shared  myMultiply.o mySum.o  -o libSharedLibrary001.so
```

Note that I did not use -fPIC.

Then, I linked the library to a Fortran program. It ran correctly.

So, my question is whether I have to use -fPIC to create a shared object library?

Comment: How did you use the shared library? Can you post details about that linking process?

Comment: I used the following comands. `gfortran -Wall -c main.f90` and
`gfortran -o myProg main.o -L. -lSharedLibrary001`. Then, I got the executable myProg and it ran correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to use -fPIC to create a shared object library?

It depends on your distro and the version of that distro's GCC toolchain
that you are using.

Many distros have been moving in recent years to GCC builds that
generate position-independent executables by default, in the interest of greater
security (such executables can run in the presence of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)).

This build configuration effectively makes `-fPIC` a default in compilation and
requires you to specify `-fno-pic` if you don't want it. The configuration is
selected by specifying the `configure` option `--enable-default-pie` when building GCC.
If you run a `gfortran` compilation in verbose mode (`-v`) and examine the output
line commencing `Configured with:`, you should see `--enable-default-pie` among
the listed configuration options.

Position-independent executables aren't universal yet and won't be for at least years. Meantime better use `-fPIC` appropriately unless you know that target user(s) or reader(s) of your build commands have an `--enable-default-pie` toolchain. It will do no harm to specify it even if it is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. 

My distro is Ubuntu 18.04 and the version of gfortran is (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3). I tried `gfortran -v` and did see `--enable-default-pie`. 

I have the following question:  is it a good practice to still use `-fPIC` to create a shared object? Or, it is not necessary at all. Thanks.

Comment: @rltang Hi. Updated answer